# Artifactory Pro Rest API to fetch Used By artifact information

Tags: rest, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am looking into getting the "reverse dependencies" of an artifact from the Rest API of Artifactory. The information is already present in the "Builds" section of the artifact. I dug a bit deeper and the call to the UI API is exactly what I would be looking for ([root]/artifactory/ui/artifactbuilds?...), but this is not an official endpoint.

How would I get the "raw" information from the "official" Rest API ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) query for getting all the builds an artifact is part of:

```
builds.find({"module.artifact.name":{"$eq":"my-artifact.jar"}})
```

To run the query use the [AQL search](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) REST API method